# How to define a BUGS/JAGS or WinBUGS model with a likelihood node that includes two integrals?

Tags: jags, bugs

I would like to implement a BUGS/WINBUGS or JAGS model that specifies the likelihood node by marginalizing over two parameters.
Is this feasible in BUGS/WINBUGS or JAGS?

This is the posterior
\begin{align}
&P\left( g_{x} , g_{y} | \mathbf{a}\right) \propto P\left( \mathbf{a} | g_{x} , g_{y}\right) P\left( g_{x} , g_{y}\right) 
\end{align}
and here is the likelihood
\begin{align}
&P\left( \mathbf{a} | g_{x} , g_{y}\right) = \int_{\boldsymbol{\omega}_{R}}\int_{\boldsymbol{\omega}_{T}}P\left( \mathbf{a} | g_{x} , g_{y} ,  \boldsymbol{\omega}_{R} , \boldsymbol{\omega}_{T}\right)P\left( \boldsymbol{\omega}_{R}\right) P\left( \boldsymbol{\omega}_{T}\right)\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}_{R} \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}_{T}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\omega}_{R} \\
\boldsymbol{\omega}_{T} \\
g_{x}\\
g_{y} \\
\end{align}
are all stochastic nodes